# expected end of statement vba program

Tags: vba

I am trying to copy an excel file from a different folder to the folder in which this script is saved/present. I am getting an "Expected End of Statement" error in my code below, can someone please help.

```
Option Explicit

Dim FSO
Dim sFile As String
Dim sSFolder As String
Dim sDFolder
Dim anObject As Object
sFile = "Filename.xlsm"
sSFolder = "C:\workspace"
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
sDFolder = FSO.GetAbsolutePathName("C:\") 
If Not FSO.FileExists(sSFolder & sFile) Then
    MsgBox "Specified File Not Found", vbInformation, "Not Found"
Else
    FSO.CopyFile (sSFolder & sFile), sDFolder, True
End If
```

Comment: Executable VBA code outside a procedure scope is illegal. Wrap everything under `Option Explicit` with a `Sub` statement, e.g. `Public Sub DoSomething()`

Comment: Actually when i put the same code in excel and try to run as macro it works but when i put it outside any excel and try to run via cmd line it gives end of statement error I have tried various stuff to solve but not getting it solved. Thank you  for help but still it is not working

Comment: VBA and vbscript are not the same thing, so maybe that's the basis of your problem?

Comment: Okay thanks i will change my code

Comment: VBScript doesn't have an `As` keyword, for one. It would help if you knew what language you're using, and if your question mentioned what statement is errorring. I'm suspecting VBScript and the first `As` clause in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but you cannot use VBA code without segmenting it into subprocedures. You should start a statement with `Sub (your subname)` and close it with `End Sub` . See below.

```
Option Explicit
Sub MyCode

Dim FSO
Dim sFile As String
Dim sSFolder As String
Dim sDFolder
Dim anObject As Object
sFile = "Filename.xlsm"
sSFolder = "C:\workspace"
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
sDFolder = FSO.GetAbsolutePathName("C:\") 
If Not FSO.FileExists(sSFolder & sFile) Then
    MsgBox "Specified File Not Found", vbInformation, "Not Found"
Else
    FSO.CopyFile (sSFolder & sFile), sDFolder, True
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

One change I would make to your code (I would have made this a comment but I don't have enough points to do so, so apologies):

sFile = "Filename.xlsm"

sSFolder = "C:\workspace\"

You are going to be looking otherwise for a file called  C:\workspaceFilename.xlsm